# Going to or progressive in that case

Tags: progressive-aspect

What is the best

If it is still not raining in the next few days,I'll go to the swimming pool

If it is not going to rain in the next few days,I'll go to the swimming pool

Comment: Your context is not clear.  Are you talking about the weather forecast determining whether you go to the pool or not, or are you talking about seeing what the whether actually does over the next several days?

Comment: Whatever you use, I'd go for contractions.

Comment: You can "go to the swimming pool" or "go swimming."  You can't "go to the swimming."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean different things.

`If it is still not raining in the next few days, I will go to the swimming pool.` means that I will wait for a few day and, if it has not rained in that time, I will go to the pool.

`If it is not going to rain in the next few days, I will go to the swimming pool.` means that if I predict that it will not rain for a few days, I will go to the pool.  I will not necessarily wait for those few non-rain days.

Comment: If it is not raining does it mean the same as if it is not going to rain

Comment: @user5577:  No. *going to* is a prediction for the future.